# "This computer is for you to attend lectures" instead of "*This computer is to attend lectures."

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, to-infinitive

I learned that you use "for -ing" and not a 'to' infinitive when you want to say the purpose of a tool,  but I am not so sure about it.

People told me I should say:

> This computer is for you to attend lectures. (1a)

or

> This computer is for attending lectures. (1b)

but not

> This computer is to attend lectures. (1c)

However, can't a 'to' infinitive alone be used as an adjective to indicate the purpose? For example, can't I say:

> You have a computer to attend class. (2a)

instead of

> You have a computer **for** you to attend class. (2b)

If I can, what do you think makes such a difference between the 1s and 2s?

Comment: to plus an infinitive is not an adjective.  You have a computer to [do something] is a verbal phrase.

Comment: I would much prefer something like "This computer is for you to use _when you attend_ lectures.", or "This computer is for you to use _when attending_ lectures.", or even "This computer is for you to use in (or for) lectures." But what happens the rest of the time? Is using the computer forbidden?

Comment: Hi ! I got the idea of this sentence from my memory with my parents I used to play too much game and I asked them to get me a computer telling them I needed one to attend lectures.

Comment: As others have said, to + verb is a verb, not an adjective. Also, what you're saying is not clear. The way you've written this, it's like you need the computer to attend class, when clearly, you can attend a class without a computer just as well. Lastly why say *computer* when you mean *laptop* or *tablet*? You're not going to drag a desktop computer along with you to class. It's much better to say *This laptop is to be used for schoolwork.*

Comment: thanks for your comment. Well I meant virtual lectures. On a second thought it might be understood in the way I take the desktop to classes haha. yes "to infinitive" is not an adjective but I learned that it can be used as if it were an adjective??

Comment: "This computer is to attend lectures" suggests to me an image of the computer going to the lecture on its own!

Comment: I agree with @Kate, "This computer is to attend lectures." might not be used because it sounds like someone has decided that the computer must attend class, not that the computer will be *used* to attend lectures. That is why the rule is for something (like a tool) that is used to do something else. You can say "the tool is for fixing grammar" or "the purpose of the tool is to fix grammar" but not "the tool is to fix grammar" (although in context, people would probably understand all of those to mean the same thing)

Comment: The most natural way of saying this without having the problem Kate and Colleen mentioned, the one that I think would occur to most native English speakers in casual conversation, is "This computer is to attend lectures with".  *But* putting "with" at the that would be an example of ending a sentence with a preposition, which some people say breaks a rule of grammar, although there's disagreement about whether that's a real rule.  I suspect that Karl's friends' insistence on "for you" is actually a laborious attempt to avoid the "with" version in case someone thinks they don't know grammar!

Comment: I see so many opinions!! I really appreciate all of your comments  Thank you have a goodnight!

Comment: @Kate Perhaps not as crazy now as it may have sounded even ten years ago. The only question seems to be whether the computer acquires sensations such as boredom, curiosity, anger, and (heaven forbid) opinions. But I remain slightly puzzled as to how a human uses a computer at lectures - to write essays, or do research, yes. But at lectures?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where you got this idea that an infinitive cannot be used to indicate purpose.

> You can borrow the car to go to school

is perfectly proper.

Comment: I think the sticky point is better phrased as "The car is to go to school, not to drive your friends to the mall". instead of "The car is for going to school, not for driving your friends to the mall."

Comment: @ColleenV Sorry to be dim. Are you disagreeing with my answer altogether or just suggesting that it could be phrased better? I am happy to edit or delete, but here I am not sure which you are recommending.

Comment: I'd say *The car is for going to school, not for going to the mall*. As long as the sentence is relatively short, *for* works well.

Comment: @FeliniusRex So you would say “You can borrow the car to go to school” is not idiomatic but “You can borrow the card for going to school” is?

Comment: I’m not disagreeing with what you’ve said, but I think the OP is asking about a different construction. ‘This tool is for fixing things” vs “*This tool is to fix things”, but they aren’t asking about “You can use this tool to fix things”.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion lies in the weird phrasing of the sentence.
1b) sounds okay, but 1a) does not.

A better way of phrasing 1a) would be:

> You have this computer so that you can attend lectures.

or

> This computer allows you to attend lectures

Then it is clear that you can use the infinitive for purpose.

1c) is not correct because you can't put an infinitive after "is". When you use "is", you need to have something that describes a state or action after that.

Vs. in 2a), the main action is "have":

> You **have** a computer **to attend** class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not attending lectures in person (as per your note), then you should not use "attend." Attend implies you are going to the lecture in person.

Since it is a virtual lecture, you can say, "Use this computer for your virtual classes."